# How should I interpret the case where elasticnet gives zero features

Tags: feature-selection, importance, elastic-net

I am using elasticnet for the purpose of determining feature importance. In case it is relevant, this is a high-dimensionality model with $n\ll p$.

I have seen cases before where Lasso, i.e. logistic regression with Lasso regularization, gives the best fit to the model with no features (intercept only). However, elasticnet with a suitable $0<\alpha<1$ does have some features in the optimized model. If I am not mistaken, this indicates a statistically significant linear correlation between the features and the outcome.

Now I have model where elasticnet always has 0 features (except in the degenerate case of Ridge Regression). Does this mean there is no statistically significant linear relation between the features and the outcome?

Comment: What do you mean by "statistically significant"?  You aren't using this phrase in a standard sense.

Comment: I'm not sure of the standard sense. Should I simply be asking whether any of the coefficients are nonzero with statistical significance?

Comment: Aside from the usage of "statistical significance" what does it "mean" that the elasticnet fit is intercept only?

Comment: ElasticNet is used to create good predictions, not to assess the "significance" or lack thereof of coefficients.  Thus, when it returns only an intercept, it is indicating none of your variables has any discernible value in improving the simple prediction made by averaging all the data (where the average is understood in a general sense appropriate to the link function).

Comment: Actually, no. I was using Lasso, and more generally elasticnet, for feature selection and not for prediction.

Comment: Nevetheless, unless you are prespecifying the value of the regularization parameter, the way ElasticNet works is through cross-validation of predicted values.  Your intentions do not change that.

Comment: OK, that does make sense. I presumably would get some feature selection by using a weaker penalty coefficient than the one given by CV, for whatever that is worth.